# To fill all space after div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How can I set the width of the right div in a percentage, so that it would fill all space after the left div?

```html
<div id='wrap'>
    <div id='left'></div>
    <div id='right'></div>
</div>
```

```css
#wrap {
    border: 5px solid green;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
}
#left {
    background: black;
    position: relative;
    top:0;
    left: 0;
    width: 90px;
    height: 100px;
    float:left;
}
#right {
    background: grey;
    position: relative;
    top:0;
    right: 0;
    height: 100px;
    float:right;
}
```

Tried it:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var x = $('#left').width();
    $('#right').width((100 - x) + '%');
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5cuH2/2/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `calc()` property in css3:

```
#right{
 width: calc(100% - 100px); /*<---do it here*/
 background: grey;
 position: relative;
 top:0;
 right: 0;
 height: 100px;
}
```

Not sure but you can also do this with `display` property with `table, table-row, table-cell`:

```
#wrap {
   border: 5px solid green;
   float: left;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100px;
   display:table; /*<----here*/
}
#left {
   background: black;
   position: relative;
   top:0;
   left: 0;
   width: 90px;
   height: 100px;
   display:table-cell;  /*<----here*/
}
#right {
   background: grey;
   position: relative;
   top:0;
   right: 0;
   height: 100px;
   display:table-cell;  /*<----here*/
}
```

Comment: Note that this won't work in older IEs and some mobile browsers. And using `calc()` here is pretty unnecessary too.

Comment: @Juhana Yes that's why i posted another option in this case with display property of css with `table`.

Comment: ...and using table cells is just too convoluted for such a simple task. You could just float the other element and be done with it. http://jsfiddle.net/tt94T/

Answer (score 1):

You can set the background color of the wrapping div to grey and then overlay the left part with your left div. This way you don't need any JS calculations.

**Check updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5cuH2/6/**

**CSS**

```
#wrap{
  border: 5px solid green;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: grey;
}
#left{
  background: black;
  position: relative;
  top:0;
  left: 0;
  width: 90px;
  height: 100px; 
  float:left;
}
#right{
  position: relative;
  top:0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100px;
  float:right;
}

.clear {
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: CSS-only solution is pretty good, but it could be done even simpler: you can drop `float:right` and positioning from the #right element and it'll still work and you don't need to move the background color to the wrapper element. http://jsfiddle.net/tt94T/

Comment: True! Also have to add a higher z-index to the #left element to make it overlay the #right container.

Answer (score 0):

try this http://jsfiddle.net/5cuH2/15/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var wrap = $('#wrap').width();
    var left = $('#left').width();
    $('#right').width((wrap-left) + 'px');
});
```

Comment: check the fiddle link

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    var x = $('#left').width();

    var total = $('#wrap').width();

    $('#right').css({
        width: total - x + "px"
    });
});
```

**OR**

```
var x = $('#left').width();
    var total = $('#wrap').width();
    var leftPer = x * 100 / total;
    $('#right').css({
        width: 100 - leftPer + "%"
    });
```

> [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5cuH2/24/)

---

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var x = ($('#left').width()/$('#wrap').width())*100;
 $('#right').width((100 - x) + '%');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var dx = $('#wrap').width();
var x = $('#left').width();
$('#right').width((dx - x) + 'px');
```

Comment: please elaborate on your answer with some explanation of the code and how it solves the problem to help others who come to this page in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Use `display:flex`.Depending on the browser implementation you will have to use'webkit,moz .. as prefixes.'
[Flex tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex)

[Flex Browser Support](http://caniuse.com/flexbox)

Working Sample:[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sunil_hari/L29AH/2/)